# Executing SAME program on both Android and JVM using different libraries

Tags: java, android, cross-platform

My code needs to migrate between a linux machine and an Android mobile. It does basic image processing and uses ImageIO on linux and BitmapFactory on Android to load jpeg images. So, I detect the environment and call the appropriate methods as below:

```
   if (isDalvik()) {
      Bitmap bi = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("test.jpg"));                                                                                        
      this.findFaces_Android(bi, 1, 40, new File("result.jpg"));
   } else {
     BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(Exp_Starter.class.getResourceAsStream("test.jpg"));
     this.findFaces_J2SE(bi, 1, 40, new File("result.jpg"));
   }
```

This works fine on Linux as I have placed the android.jar in the class path. However, it fails to work on Android. When started, it claims about not finding BufferedImage and ImageIO classes, although they are never actually called as the else statement will not be executed.

I tried to create empty classes of java.awt.image.BufferedImage and javax.imageio.ImageIO for the Android application but compiler does not allow overwriting them.

Any idea about how to fix this problem and making the SAME program work on both different environments?

Comment: Wouldn't you need to add those jars to the class path as you did on Linux ?

Comment: Try moving the else part into a separate method.

Comment: The code is first compiled for errors and then executed. at compilation time, it does not check the if-else, it only converts the statements. so even though it does not need to execute bufferedImage and ImageIO, it still needs class for that. hence you are getting an error.

Comment: @AdmiralAdama those jars are standard Java library and thus cannot be specified in class path. In fact, Compiler will quit if you try to overwrite one of those as class path.

Comment: @HansKratz Moving them to a separate method did not help. but that gave me the idea of putting them in separate classes and instantiate those classes based on the run environment. This in fact worked. Thanks for the idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, moving the code for different runtime environment to different classes solves the problem. Here's what worked for me:

```
if (isDalvik()) {
  Find_Faces_Android ff = new Find_Faces_Android();   
  ff.readImage(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("test.jpg"));
  int no_detected_faces = ff.findFaces( 1, 40, new File("result.jpg"));
} else {
  Find_Faces_JVM ff = new Find_Faces_JVM();
  ff.readImage(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("test.jpg"));
  int no_detected_faces = ff.findFaces( 1, 40, new File("result.jpg"));
}
```